# Errno 101 Network is unreachable after WIFI disconnect, but what about localhost?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, udp, wifi, multicast

I have the following Python class

```
class MultiCast():
  def sendMessage(self, message):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, struct.pack('b', 5))
    sock.sendto(message, ('227.0.0.1', 12345))
    sock.close()
multicast = MultiCast()
```

which I then use by calling `multicast.sendMessage('text')`.

On the same Linux machine I have a client which joins that group and listens to those messages, occasionally I also join that group from other machines in the LAN for debugging (they contain processed retransmissions of a GPS receiver).

The issue is that when the WIFI connection is lost (it's running on a laptop), `sock.sendto(message, ('227.0.0.1', 12345))` throws an exception `sock.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable`

I was under the impression that losing that WIFI connection shouldn't have any effect at all, since there's still the localhost interface to be served. I thought the messages were sent to all the avaliable interfaces.

How can I deal with this issue? The multicast client on the same machine should still be able to receive those multicast messages, regardless of the WIFI connection status.

Replacing the relevant code with the broadcast variant also shows the same problem.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.sendto(message, ('<broadcast>', 12345))
sock.close()
```

## ----

I've continued to deal with this issue, and the following is the most "usable" solution. I do not know if it is the recommended approach, but I'll use it for now, until someone can help me to deal with this issue properly.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, struct.pack('b', 5))
try:
  # print 'multicast'
  sock.sendto(message, ('228.0.0.5', 12345))
except:
  # print 'localhost fallback'
  sock.sendto(message, ('127.0.0.5', 12345))
sock.close()
```

Is there a way to check beforehand if sending to `228.0.0.5` would fail instead of relying on exceptions?